# Differentiability of an even function

Tags: derivatives

If $f$ is an even function such that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ has a finite non zero value , then is $f(x)$ continuous , differentiable , or neither continuous nor differentiable at $x=0$?

I think that the function is continuous , and it is easy to prove that too. But it would not be differentiable. This is because , the above expression represents the derivative of the function at $x=0$ and and the derivative of an even function at $0$ is always zero however according to the given question , the derivative of the function is not zero. So it is not differentiable. Do you think I have reasoned it correctly ?

[image]

Comment: The limit you wrote is the definition of the derivative. Do you really want that one or a lateral one like $x\to0^+$?

Comment: No according to the given question it’s just $x \to 0$

Comment: You say the derivative of an even function at $0$ is always zero; to make this true, you should add the phrase: "if it exists". Many even functions are not differentiable at $x=0$

Comment: If the function is even, and that two-sided limit is non-zero, then we have a contradiction. :/

Comment: @Aditi Then everything is true, because on one hand you know that limit exists and it is non-zero, on the other you know that for an even function if that limit exists it should be zero.

Comment: But if he derivative exists , it still wouldn’t be differentiable by the reason I’ve stated right ? Or would there be another reason for it’s non differentiability?

Comment: @scentofthetrees okay ! That’s what I wanted to know! Thanks !

Comment: @Aditi Take into account that by "everything is true" I really mean everything. $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is not differentiable, $f$ is continuous, $f$ is not continuous, ...

Comment: @scentofthetrees the above question was a multiple choice question which had three choices : continuous and differentiable , discontinuous and not differentiable , or just discontinuous

Comment: @Aditi If that's the case, then it's not a valid question. Do you still have a copy of the question available? Could you post the question exactly (ideally, both a transcript and a photo of the question)?

Comment: @Tanner Okay ! Well just to add a detail, the question had four choices of which the last one was none of these . I thought it was redundant earlier since the answer to the question was continuous but non differentiable but just wanted to check if I’d reasoned it correctly

Comment: If the answer is continuous, but not differentiable, then I am convinced that the information given <strike>was</strike> should have been only the lateral limit.

Comment: @scentofthetrees have a look at the original question please

Comment: @Aditi I did. For the question as written, all (a),(b),(c),(d) are true. There is clearly a typo, and the given limit should just be a lateral limit, in which case the answer is (b).

Comment: Given that the authors of the book cannot decide if a function is "derivable" or "differentiable" at $x=0$, it is no wonder that there are other, more important, typos.

Comment: @scentofthetrees alright thank you for your time :)

Comment: It might be helpful if we knew which book this is from.  It might also be useful to send an email to the author(s) and point out the error (or see if there are errata which correct the error).

Comment: @Xander I do know this book . Would you like to know it too ?

Comment: I wouldn't have asked if I didn't want an answer.

Comment: @Xander I’m sorry. The book is the calculus edition of Cengage publications . It’s a book for high school students aiming for entrance examinations in India .

Comment: This problem appears to be from page 12.8 of [The Pearson Guide To Complete Mathematics For The Aieee, 4/E](https://books.google.com/books?id=u7HWgE60km4C&pg=SA12-PA8).  I cannot find any errata online.

Comment: @Xander quite true. The general trend in these books is that they circulate almost the same question over again in different books so it’s hard to decipher who had originally formulated it. This specific question was from a daily practice problems book of cengage publications and I think it would be hard to find that specific book online. Thanks a lot for your help and time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the [Principle of Explosion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion), all answers are correct.  There are two contradictory statements in the question:

- It is stated that $f'(0)$ exists (because the limit of the difference quotient exists) and that $f$ is even.  Hence
  \begin{align} f'(0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
  &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(-h)-f(0)}{h} \\
  &= \lim_{-h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{-h} \\
  &= -\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} \\
  &= -f'(0).
  \end{align}
  Since $f'(0) = -f'(0)$, it must be the case that $f'(0) = 0$.
- It is also state that $f'(0)$ exists and $f'(0) > 0$.

These two statements are contradictory, therefore any conclusion follows.  The correct answer, then, is to mark all of the multiple choice options. ;)

---

While it is impossible to know, it is likely that (as has been pointed out in the comments) the author(s) intended to consider the one sided limit.  It is reasonable to conclude that the question should have read

> If $f$ is an even function such that
>   $$ \lim_{h\to 0^+} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} $$
>   has some finite, non-zero value, then... (multiple choice options).

In this case, there is no contradiction.  Then, by the reasoning above, we know that the function cannot be differentiable at $x=0$.  If it were, then the derivative would be zero, but we know that it is not.

On the other hand, suppose that the one-sided limit is $L$, i.e. that $\lim_{h\to 0^+} (f(h)-f(0))/h = L$.  Then
$$ |f(h) - f(0)|
= \left| h \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} \right|
= |h| \left|  \frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} \right|
= |h| |L|. $$
We can make this as small as we like by choosing $h$ sufficiently small.  The limit from the left will be the same (the sign of the limits will differ, but this is absorbed into the absolute value).  This implies that $f$ is continuous at zero.  Therefore, assuming that the question was supposed to read as indicated above, the correct answer would be (b).

Comment: Thank you ! But do you think it is correct to not consider the lateral limit and only conclude it on the basis of the derivative tending to zero , and the derivative at zero, i.e. , the function does not have a derivative because it’s derivative tending to zero and that at zero is different?

Comment: Unless otherwise stated, a limit is two-sided.  If the author(s) had wanted you to consider a one-sided limit, then they should have indicated so.

Comment: Alright ! Thanks for your help !

Comment: Thanks for the edit ! I’d earlier thought about it too but I was confused as well because the author hadn’t explicitly specified a one sided limit

Answer (score 2):

Well, the given question isn't really valid, because it's *not possible* for $f$ to be an even function such that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ has a finite non zero value.

Your reasoning isn't really correct, because you should have concluded that the given conditions are impossible. "The function is not differentiable at $0$" is not the correct conclusion to come to.

In my opinion, none of the given answer choices are accurate.

Comment: Right I understand thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

So I think the answer is that the you are right: function is continuous but not differentiable.

I am assuming that the question meant 'limit from the positive direction' otherwise, as others have pointed out, the question is contradictory. However this is a reasonable assumption because with this assumption the question becomes meaningful and interesting.

The limit 'from the right; the positive side' is non-zero. The function is even and so the limit that comes from the left (the negative side) will have the opposite sign. And so these two limits cannot be equal (because they are non-zero) which means that the function does not have a derivative. For a mental picture, imagine two straight lines (one from the top right and one from the top left) into the origin and forming a point. At the origin there is no derivative.

But the function is continuous essentially because we can make the distance between $f(h)$ and $f(0)$ as small we we please by making $h$ small and then the difference between $f(h)$ and $f(0)$ will look like $h.l$ where $l$ is the limit of $(f(h)-f(0))/h$. We will be able to do something similar (with reversed sign) from the other side because $f$ is even. So, yes, I think you are right: $f$ is continuous but not differentiable.

Comment: Hi ! I did know the answer to the question already . However I had not considered two sided limits while evaluating it. I had just considered the derivative that was tending to zero and the derivative at zero. As these two were not equal , I concluded that the function is not differentiable. I just wanted to know whether it was correct to not consider two sided limits

Comment: Aha, that makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks for you help anyways !

Comment: It was good to speak - interesting problem!

Comment: May I suggest that you edit your answer to move the "PS" to the top and make it clear from the start that you are making this assumption?